How to stick the horizontal scroll bar in mat-mdc-tab-body-content so it's visible at all times
I want to make the horizontal scrollbar inside the .mat-mdc-tab-body-content always visible not only when the user is at the bottom of the page. Is it possible? Has anyone tried something similar?
